# Why is the variable declared in ComponentWillMount Undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component of this type. For simplicity, I have removed all unnecessary code.

This component displays a button when clicking on which the value of the variable I declared in `ComponentWillMount` should be displayed in the console, but when clicked, the console displays undefined, why?

```
    'use strict';
    class LoginFormComponent extends React.Component {

      handleSubmit() {
        console.log(this.model); //undefined
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        this.model = 123;
      }

      render() {
                    console.log(this.model);  //123
        var styles = this.props.styles;

        return (
                <CM.MUI.FlatButton
                style={styles.buttonStyle}
                onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                label={CM.gettext('Login')}/>
        );
      }
    };

    module.exports = LoginFormComponent;
```

Comment: I have added more details to the answer. Thanks! 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `componentDidMount` for setting up the instance properties as the content in `componentWillMount` will not be in the instance scope as the component isn't mounted yet.

Also, use a `=>` fat arrow function to get the access to `this` instance of your component.

Updated Code:

```js
class LoginFormComponent extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(this.model); // 123
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.model = 123;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.model); //123
    var styles = this.props.styles;

    return (
      <CM.MUI.FlatButton
        style={styles.buttonStyle}
        onClick={this.handleSubmit}
        label={CM.gettext("Login")}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default LoginFormComponent;
```

**Console**

[image: preview]

**Demo: [agitated-solomon-3rrow - CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-solomon-3rrow)**

**More information**

As explained in this demo: [summer-violet-g4pyd - CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-violet-g4pyd), it looks like the way React works is as follows:

1. Constructor
2. componentWillMount
3. Render
4. componentDidMount

So after the `render()` is executed, the `componentDidMount` is getting executed and there's **no change** after any state change.

[image: preveiw]

If you want something to be there, please put them in `constructor()`.

Moreover, `componentWillMount` is deprecated and you should not use that in the next releases.

Answer (score 2):

Because by writing `onClick = {this.handleSubmit}` you detach the function from the context, and in this function you have this - not your component
Try to write

```
onClick = {this.handleSubmit.bind (this)}
```

or

```
handleSubmit = () => {console.log (this.model)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code declared in `componentWillMount` will not be in the instance scope for a simple reason: The component isn't mounted yet. If you want to declare a global property in your class, just use `componentDidMount` or declare it inside the class body like any other method.

Answer (score 1):

First, `model` seems to be a used as a state field, so as stated in the `React` docs :

> Typically, in React constructors are only used for two purposes:
>
> - Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state.
> - Binding event handler methods to an instance.
>
> You should not call setState() in the constructor(). Instead, if your component needs to use local state, assign the initial state to this.state directly in the constructor:

So you should first define your state using:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state.model = 123; // or
    this.state = {          // commonly used syntax
        model : 123
    }
}
```

Then still according to the docs :

> UNSAFE_componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead for initializing state.

You are indeed using this to initialize your component's state. As pointed by others, you should instead use `ComponentDidMount` and use `this.setState` to modify the state as modifying the state directly with `this.state.model` is considered bad behaviour

> Constructor is the only place where you should assign this.state directly. In all other methods, you need to use this.setState() instead.

Please check : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html for more informations

Answer (score 1):

I think `this.modal` refers to the FlatButton component instead, can you bind the `handleSubmit` to LoginFormComponent?

```
    class LoginFormComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }
      handleSubmit() {
      ...
```